# What are some simple examples of using throw, try, and catch for exceptions? I do not have a solid understanding of any of these

Tags: php, exception, try-catch, throw

So i've already read all of the exmaples on php.net. And none of their exmaples really stuck with me. I know what exceptions are used for, just not how to properly use throw, try, and catch in my code. Also, I was wondering if this was only used for OOP? Or just any PHP code? I have no idea what to do with "throw new exception". All i know is code goes inside try block, and catch is supposed to handle the errors if any occur. Please help!

Comment: Have you tried reading the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pseudo code since this is useful in more than just PHP.

Sometimes methods will run into problems that they can't (or don't want to) deal with. Say we have a `sendExDrunkenText($ex)` method. This expects an `$ex` argument and will lookup that ex girlfriend and send them a rambling SMS.

If this method can't find find the `$ex` supplied an alternative to returning false or the like is to throw some kind of exception:

```
if(! exExists($ex)){
    throw NoSuchExException("Cant't find supplied ex");
}
```

(As an aside in precompiled languages - i.e. java - you can require that a method calling your method either deals with or rethrows your exception. For this reason imo exceptions are more useful in these languages).

Now if you are using the above method you may want to take some action if an exception is thrown. In that case you can catch the exception and deal with it appropriately:

```
foreach($exList as $ex){
    try{
          sendExDrunkenText($ex);
    }catch(NoSuchExException $exception){
        removeFromAddressBook($ex);
    }

}
```

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Wow, nice exmaples! Haha thankyou very much! That cleared it up a lot!

Comment: But wait, in your catch block, what does the argument $exception stand for? And also, is this all hypothetically inside a class?

Comment: @EricDiviney `$exception` is the exception that is caught (i.e. the one thrown inside `sendDrunkenText`. This will contain the message and could give other details about the exception too. It's more common to see exception handling with classes and the like but this can be used in any PHP code.

Comment: Ah! I see now! Okay thanks very much for everything!

Answer (score 0):

When you want to stop the execution because something is wrong, throw an error (instead of die() or continuing execution with unpredictable results).

Even if the thrown exception is not caught with a try catch block, it will still be possible to get a stack trace, a line number and a file path to ease debugging.

Exceptions are the best error handling mechanism in PHP. They will help you find and throw errors to ease debugging.